# How do I know which regiments are lower social standing?

Tags: en-garde

For [joining regiments](http://patriot.net/~aquazoo/eg/eg_rules/eg_mil.html) the rules state:

> "A player who unsuccessfully attempts to join a regiment may apply to
>   other regiments in the same week, but may only apply to regiments of
>   lower social standing than the one to which he was denied admission."

**This appears different to SL, so what table/indicator is used to determine what regiments are of "lower social standing"?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote the rules:

> The social standing of the regiments is the order in which they are listed on Regiment table A, the Royal Foot Guards being the highest and the frontier regiments the lowest.

It's exactly the next sentence after what you've quoted.

Comment: Doooooh! Walls of text are harsh on the eyes. Thanks.